# Solidity timeout error Remix Chainlink interface Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, remix, rinkeby, chainlink

I am following Patrick Collin's smart contract course on youtube and am stuck at the 2hr 46min mark (FundMe.sol) ETH/USD Chainlink price feed on rinkeby.

The code from the video compiles ok but when i try to deploy to rinkeby, my metamask does not pop up and i get the following error:

"creation of FundMe errored: [TIMEOUT] Timeout for call deployMetadataOf from udapp"

Here is the code I am using in REMIX.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

 
contract FundMe {

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // what the ETH -> USD conversion rate  
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
}
```

To try and fix the problem I started over creating FundMe.sol from the beginning and changed versions to "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" incase the one in the video was no longer correct. I also tried to copy paste the entire code instead of just importing.

Comment: Hi @JMG, what IDE or software are you using when creating and compiling your contract? Are you using remix, VS Code etc?

Comment: Hi @JMG I just tried your code in remix and I was able to deploy on Rinkeby. Here are the steps, please follow and let me know how you go: 
1 - paste code above in remix
2 - compile code
3 - go to remix run tab
4 - change contract drop down to 'FundMe'
5 - ensure environment drop down is set to Injected web3, and that your metamask is connected to Rinkeby
6 - Press the deploy button

Comment: Hello @Harry, it worked! thanks, I think i must have had my metamask connected to kovan from something earlier in the course.

Comment: Hmm.. wondering what this issue was. If someone can reproduce and come to a conclusion as an answer that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i just deactivated my brave shield/ ad blocker and it worked !